# How to convert a string into a object

Tags: javascript, json

I've a string value in the format `'{"apple":30,"orange":50}'`. How can I convert it into a javascript object of format

```
{apple: 30, orange: 50}
```

So that I can get the value for `apple` by using `object.apple`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this by many methods but I prefer to use a library like the [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js) from [Mr. Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/).

If you use the library it is as simple as

```
var object = JSON.parse('{"apple":30,"orange":50}')
alert(object.apple) // will alert 30
```

The most dangerous and ugly way is to use the `eval()` function.

```
eval('object={"apple":30,"orange":50}')
alert(object.apple) // will alert 30
```

Never use this.

The [json.org](http://www.json.org/) site has references to more json libraries in different languages. [Javascript specific information](http://www.json.org/js.html) can be found [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: +1 Crockford actually now provides three different parse libraries depending on your preferences, all of which can be found [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) *(that's a link; stoopid StackOverflow not underlining links)*. There's the original `json2.js`, which does use `eval` under the covers but does some checks first to see if it looks okay, and two options that don't use `eval`: `json_parse.js` which uses a recursive-descent parser, and `json_parse_state.js` which uses a state machine. A selection of choices!

Comment: @Eric, but the nice part is that `json2.js` won't override it, and the native API was deliberately made compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Crockford's JSON parser](http://www.json.org/js.html)

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"apple":30,"orange":50}');
// obj.apple === 30
```